# BigQuery Java client throws NullPointerException while using ServiceAccountCredentials on GCP Dataflow runner Apache-beam

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am running apache-beam pipeline using dataflowRunner. Inside pipeline I am able to write moderate amount of data to bigquery table from csv file. I am using ServiceAccountCredentials using json file. For bigger data I get following exception which suggest that the code is not able to get the refresh token.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken(ServiceAccountCredentials.java:342)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.refresh(OAuth2Credentials.java:149)
        at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.getRequestMetadata(OAuth2Credentials.java:135)
        at com.google.auth.http.HttpCredentialsAdapter.initialize(HttpCredentialsAdapter.java:96)
        at com.google.cloud.http.HttpTransportOptions$1.initialize(HttpTransportOptions.java:157)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:93)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory.buildPostRequest(HttpRequestFactory.java:133)
        at com.google.cloud.bigquery.spi.v2.HttpBigQueryRpc.open(HttpBigQueryRpc.java:403)
        at com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableDataWriteChannel$2.call(TableDataWriteChannel.java:78)
        at com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableDataWriteChannel$2.call(TableDataWriteChannel.java:75)
        at com.google.api.gax.retrying.DirectRetryingExecutor.submit(DirectRetryingExecutor.java:91)
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.run(RetryHelper.java:74)
        at com.google.cloud.RetryHelper.runWithRetries(RetryHelper.java:51)
        at com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableDataWriteChannel.open(TableDataWriteChannel.java:75)
        at com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableDataWriteChannel.<init>(TableDataWriteChannel.java:42)
        at com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryImpl.writer(BigQueryImpl.java:677)
        at com.datametica.bigsuite.web.service.pelican.transfer.transforms.DataTransferTransform.processElement(DataTransferTransform.java:74)
        at com.datametica.bigsuite.web.service.pelican.transfer.transforms.DataTransferTransform$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:177)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:138)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:324)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:272)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:66)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:436)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:424)
        at com.datametica.bigsuite.web.service.pelican.transfer.transforms.TransferCommandHolderDoFn.processElement(TransferCommandHolderDoFn.java:32)
        at com.datametica.bigsuite.web.service.pelican.transfer.transforms.TransferCommandHolderDoFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:177)
        at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:138)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:324)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:187)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:148)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:68)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:330)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:302)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:251)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:135)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:115)
        at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:102)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

below is Sample code.

```
    bigquery = PipelineLauncher.createBigQueryClient(credentials, projectId, configuration);
    TableId tableId = TableId.of(transferCommandHolder.getValue().getTargetDbName(), transferCommandHolder.getValue().getTableName());
    WriteChannelConfiguration writeChannelConfiguration = WriteChannelConfiguration.newBuilder(tableId)
            .setFormatOptions(FormatOptions.csv())
            .setSchema(transferCommandHolder.getValue().getBigQueryTargetSchema())
            .setWriteDisposition(JobInfo.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
            .build();
    TableDataWriteChannel writer = bigquery.writer(writeChannelConfiguration);
    Path csvPath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".", transferCommandHolder.getKey());

    try (OutputStream stream = Channels.newOutputStream(writer)) {
        Files.copy(csvPath, stream);
    }
    Job job = writer.getJob();
    job = job.waitFor();
    c.output(KV.of(transferCommandHolder.getKey(), null != job.getStatus().getError()));
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't simply use BigQueryIO.write() and are instead invoking the BigQuery REST API directly?

Comment: Initially I was doing BigQueryIO.write() but, the performance in terms of time was not optimum. I then changed my code to use BigQuery REST API which was giving better performance. I am able to write one million records successfully but when record count reaches around five million it is throwing NullPointerException.

Comment: Hmm, for a few million records there shouldn't be any performance issues. Could you give more details, e.g. job id of a job that used BigQueryIO.write() but was too slow, and job id of a job using the new code that is faster on the same data?

Comment: while I am running the pipeline with both the codes to share the job ids, I thought of sharing the solution that I applied for  NullPointerException. Earlier,  I was using ServiceAccountCredential to get the BigQuery client. If I change it to use default credentials using 
 BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService(); I do not get this problem. Please suggest if you see any disadvantages of using default credentials.